# How to stop wrapping comments in p tag

Tags: wordpress

After I update a comment in wordpress, the comment is wrapped with p tag.

```
remove_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_kses');
return wp_update_comment( $data );
```

I searched for this problem and [I found that I should remove the `wpautop` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop#Disabling_the_filter), and so I did.

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_kses');
return wp_update_comment( $data );
```

but the problem didn't disappear. comments are still wrapped in `<p>` tags after update. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this is by manipulating the comment content once saved.

```
// you can modify the execution order of this hook
add_action( 'comment_post', 'comment_manipulation', 10, 2 );
function comment_manipulation( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {

    // you can check for comment approved here

    // get the comment data based on ID
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID, ARRAY_A );

   // $comment['comment_content'] is accessible here.
}
```

Then you can just do a search and replace for the paragraph tags, and update the comment with the new content in the database.

---

**Edit**

Updated code that does all of the steps, however this will only remove p tags from future comments, not existing ones. This is also untested so you'd have to double check yourself.

```
add_action( 'comment_post', 'comment_manipulation', 10, 2 );
function comment_manipulation( $comment_ID, $comment_approved ) {

    // get the comment data based on ID
    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID, ARRAY_A );

    // remove only the first <p> you can find
    $new_comment = str_replace( "<p>", '', $comment['comment_content'], 1);

    // reverse the string
    $reversed = strrev($new_comment);

    // remove only the first >p/< you can find (</p> in reverse)
    $new_reversed_comment = str_replace( ">p/<", '', $reversed, 1);

    // reverse back
    $new_comment = strrev($new_reversed_comment);

    // let's update comment in database with new content
    global $wpdb;

    $comment_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'comments';
    $wpdb->get_results(
        "UPDATE $comment_table
        SET comment_content = $new_comment
        WHERE comment_ID = $comment_ID"
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I started learning wordpress lately. I don't know a lot about wordpress. could you please tell me how to check for comment approve? and how can I edit the comment this way?

Comment: I've updated the answer. The update required strictly PHP, not WordPress knowledge. You don't _have_ to do check comment approval if you'd like this done for all comments. Some sites monitor comments  and the variable `$comment_approved` is available to indicate it is approved or not (check for values 1 or 0)

Answer (score 1):

Comments are not wrapped while saving comments. Please make sure that the `wpautop` filter is not active when you output comments on page. `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );` should be placed directly in functions.php if you want to disable `wpautop` filter everywhere otherwise it should be placed somewhere before the code relevant to comments output in template and that added again after the relevant code is finished.

Comment: I'm sure that the comment is saved wrapped in p tags. When I open the database I can see the `<p></p>` tag wrapping comment's text.

Comment: Is it happening on new comments as well? Also are you using some wysiwyg editor on frontend or text area?

Comment: No, It's just happening when updating my comment. I'm not using any wysiwyg editor. I'm using a normal input box.

Comment: I'm trying to see how the function `wp_update_comment` works, and I noticed that the text is wrapped after the statement `$data = wp_unslash( $commentarr );`.

Comment: ok, check the data you're passing to comment update function `wp_update_comment( $data );`, also check raw $_POST data and see if the <p> tags are submitted by browser or generated by WordPress. You can use var_dump() or print_r() as quick and dirty approach to see the data.

Comment: `$data = wp_unslash( $commentarr );`: hmm, there should be something else as well, this function only remove slashes from array elements.